# base page inheritance from asp page

Tags: c#, asp.net, inheritance

It might sound silly question but I am stuck with this problem. The BasePage is not inherited by the web pages.

I first created the App_Code folder then created a base page BasePage.cs inside it.

```
using System;

public abstract class BasePage : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    public BasePage() { }

    protected void Page_PreInit(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //other logic
    }
}
```

Then I created a web page test.asp inside the pages directory.

```
using System;

namespace MIS.WebUsers.pages
{
    public partial class test : BasePage            
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

It is showing >> *the type or namespace 'BasePage' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)*

1. How to solve this problem, is there any settings need to be done for this ?

Comment: the directive at the top ...

`<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Styles/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="blahblah.aspx.cs" Inherits="foo.bar" %>`

tells the server what file and what class in the file is associated with the page. The code behind class also has member variables that correspond to each control on the page, and provide a way for code in the code behind file to manipulate the controls. and please refer [this article](http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/demos/printPage.aspx?path=/articles/041305-1.aspx) which may useful for you

Comment: @nischalinn change your build action to Compile

Comment: @Webruster I do not understand how your comment will solve my problem. Please explain.

Comment: @Katana I build the solution, but did not solve the problem.

Comment: @nischalinn is visual studio didn't present any option to resolve the issue?

Comment: @Katana no, it is just showing `the type or namespace 'BasePage' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)` in the code behind page. Please suggest how to solve this problem.

Comment: @Katana how to change build action to Compile in web application?

Answer (score 0):

From just looking at the code you provided you are missing:

```
namespace MIS.WebUsers.pages
```

from the BasePage class